# How often does the earth rotate around the common center of mass with the moon?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, earth, celestial-mechanics

I could not find anywhere how long does it take for the earth to rotate around the center of mass of the earth moon system, which is located inside the earth but off-center. And does this motion have any visible or named effect?

Comment: *"I could not find anywhere ..."* implies that you haven't really understood what going on here. The Earth and the Moon *both* orbit their common center of gravity in beautiful synchronicity. Can you look it up now?

Comment: Hmm, is that really a "beautiful synchronicity"? they both just go around in a circle  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what LDC3 wrote: they always have to be on opposite side of the center of mass, so they must rotate in a synchronous way. Or in  general, the period of two masses around the common center of mas is always the same.

Answer (score 3):

Since a new moon has to have the sun shine on the entire surface facing away from the Earth, the time between 2 new moons is the time for the Earth Moon system to complete a synodic period.

The period of two masses around the common center of mass is always the same.

Comment: @LDC3: No; *sidereal* means relative to distant stars. The period between two new moons is the *synodic* month. They differ -- the synodic month being longer -- because the length of a month is a significant fraction of a year, so by the time the Earth-Moon system has completed a sidereal orbit, its angle relative to the Sun has changed.

Comment: @ruakh You're right, I used the wrong word. I changed it. From new moon to new moon is a synodic period, not a sidereal period.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth and the Moon revolve about their barycenter (center of mass of the Earth/Moon system), which is inside the Earth and is about 4,670 Km from the center of the Earth on a line connecting the center of the Earth with the center of the Moon (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_(astronomy)).

The apocenter of the Moon is its center when farthest removed from the barycenter, and the pericenter of the Moon is its center at its closest to the barycenter.  A straight line passing through the center of the Earth, through the barycenter of the system, and connecting the apocenter and the pericenter of the Moon is called the line of apsides.

The period of precession of the line of apsides is about 8.85 years.  This marks one complete revolution of the Earth/Moon system about its barycenter.  However, one revolution of the Earth about the barycenter is the same as one revolution of the Moon around the barycenter, which is also one revolution of the Moon around the Earth, or about 27 1/3 days.  Both Earth and Moon must rotate about the barycenter with the same period, as Bruce Smitherson pointed out in his answer.  There is an animation in the link above which shows this.

It is interesting to note that the antikythera mechanism, a celestial computer recovered from the wreck of an ancient Greek ship which sank about 2,200 years ago, appears to have corrected for this precession of the line of apsides (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsidal_precession).